How to show that this polynomial has three roots in the disk $|z|<2$ (using Rouche)?
Using any Rouché's theorem version,
Show that
$$h(z)=z^4+3z^3-z^2+7$$
has 3 roots in $|z|<2$



Factors
factors on $|z|=2$




$z^4$
16


$3z^3$
24


$-z^2$
4


$7$
7



Using the version that says
if $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$ on $z=2$ then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros in $|z|<2$. We conclude immediately that

$h_1(z)=z^4+3z^3-z^2$ has 3 zeros in $|z|<2$
$h_2(z)=z^4+3z^3+7$ has 3 zeros in $|z|<2$
$h_3(z)=3z^3-z^2+7$ has 3 zeros in $|z|<2$
$h_4(z)=3z^3+7$ has 3 zeros in $|z|<2$
$h_5(z)=z^4+3z^3$ has 3 zeros in $|z|<2$
$h_6(z)=3z^3-z^2$ has 3 zeros in $|z|<2$
$h_7(z)=3z^3$ has 3 zeros in $|z|<2$

In all cases above, we use $f(z)=3z^3$ and $g(z)$ representing the remainder of $h_i$.
But how can we conclude the original question?

We have $h(-2)< 0$ . Thus one root $r$  is real and $r<-2.$ Besides another real root $s$ satisfies $-2<s<0.$ Perhaps it helps.

Is my solution correct? I tried a transformation.

Let $f(z)=z^4+3z^3-z^2$ and $g(z)=7$. If $|z|=2$, then$$|f(z)|=|z^4+3z^3-z^2|=\color{red}4|z^2+3z-1|.$$On the other hand, $z$ can be written as $2\cos(\theta)+2i\sin(\theta)$, for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, and then\begin{align}|z^2+3z-1|^2&=16\sin^4(\theta)+44\sin^2(\theta)+16\cos^4(\theta)+\\&\phantom{=}+48\cos^3(\theta)+28\cos^2(\theta)-12\cos(\theta)+\\&\phantom{=}+32\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)+48\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)+1\\&=36\cos(\theta)-16\cos^2(\theta)+61\end{align}(just use the fact that, for each $\theta\in\Bbb R$, $\sin^2(\theta)=1-\cos^2(\theta)$). But, if $\theta\in\Bbb R$,$$\left|36\cos(\theta)-16\cos^2(\theta)+61\right|\geqslant61-36-16=9;$$in other words, if $|z|=2$, then $|z^2+3z-1|\geqslant\color{blue}3$, and so$$|f(z)|\geqslant\color{red}4\times\color{blue}3=12>7=|g(z)|.$$So, $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros on $D_2(0)$ (if we count them with their multiplicities). But$$f(z)=0\iff z=0\vee z=-\frac32\pm\frac{\sqrt{13}}2,$$$0$ is a double root and the other two are simple roots. Of these roots, only $-\frac32-\frac{\sqrt{13}}2$ lies outside $D_2(0)$. Therefore $f$ has three roots on that disk.

We follow the idea of @José Carlos Santos, but estimates are obtained in a simpler way.
Consider $f(z)=z^4+3z^3-z^2$ and $g(z)=7.$ Next for $|z|=2$  we obtain $$|f(z)|=|z^4+3z^3-z^2|=8|z-z^{-1}+3|$$ For $z=2e^{i\theta}$ the real part of $z-z^{-1}$ is equal ${3\over 2}\cos\theta\le {3\over 2}.$ Therefore $$|f(z)|\ge |{\rm Re}\,f(z)|\ge 8\left ( 3-{3\over 2}\right )=12>7=|g(z)|$$
We have $f(z)=3z^3+(z^4-z^2).$ The function $3z^3$ has $3$ roots in $|z|<1.$ Moreover for $|z|=1$ we have $$ |3z^3|=3> 2\ge  |z^4-z^2|$$ Hence $f(z)$ admits $3$ roots in $|z|<1<2.$
Finally $z^4+3z^3-z^2+7=f(z)+g(z)$ has $3$ roots in $|z|<2.$
Remark It can be proved straightforward that $f(z)$ has three roots in $|z|<2.$ The point $0$ is a double root and for $z^2+3z-1$ the product of the roots is equal $1.$ Hence one of them lies in $(-1,1)\setminus \{0\}.$

First we can apply Rouché's theorem to $h$ and
$$
 g(z) = (z^3 -z + \frac 52) (z+3) = z^4 + 3z^3-z^2- \frac 12 z + \frac{15}{2} \, .
$$
For $|z|=2$ is
$$
 |h(z) - g(z)| = \left|\frac 12 z - \frac 12\right| \le \frac 32
$$
and
$$
 |g(z)| \ge (8 - 2 - \frac 52)(3-2) = \frac 72 \, .
$$
It follows that $h$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in $|z| < 2$, and that is the number of $\tilde g(z) = z^3-z+5/2$ in $|z| < 2$.
It remains to show that all three roots of $\tilde g$ are in $|z| < 2$. This can be done by assuming that $z^3 = z - 5/2$ with $|z| \ge 2$ and applying the triangle inequality to obtain a contradition, or by applying Rouché's theorem again to $\tilde g(z)$ and $f(z) = z^3+5/2$.

$h(z)-g(z)$ is not $-\tfrac12z-\tfrac12.$ Isn't it?

@BobDobbs: You are right, there was a sign error, thanks. Fortunately, it does not affect the calculation.

Let $z\to\frac1z.$ Then, we need to show that
$$7z^4-z^2+3z+1=0$$
has one root inside $|z|=\frac12.$
But,
$$|-z^2+3z+1|\geq\frac34>\frac7{16}=|7z^4|$$
on $|z|=\frac12$.
As Riemann noted, when $|z|=\frac12$, $|−z^2+3z+1|>|7z^4|$
also implies there is no root for $7z^4−z^2+3z+1=0$
on $|z|=1^2$. So the other three roots of $7z^4−z^2+3z+1=0$
are all contained in ${z∣|z|>\tfrac12}$
. Hence $z^4+3z^3−z^2+7=0$
has three roots in $|z|<2$
.
To show that $|-z^2+3z+1|\geq\tfrac34$ on $|z|=\tfrac12,$ let $z=\tfrac12(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ and $f(\theta)=|-z^2+3z+1|^2$. Then $f(\theta)=\frac{53}{16}-\tfrac12\cos2\theta+\tfrac94\cos\theta$ and $f'(\theta)=0$ gives the crtical points $x=0,\pi$. Minumum is $f(\pi)=\tfrac9{16}.$

It seems to be correct, but how exactly did you prove $|-z^2+3z+1|\geq\frac34$ for $|z|=1/2$? I am probably overlooking something obvious.

I asked to WalframAlpha. I think it can be done by polar substitution and derivative. @MartinR İ hope it is correct.

As I said, it looks correct. Nice idea with the inversion!

When $|z|=\frac12$, we have $$|-z^2+3z+1|=\frac12\left|3-z+\frac1z\right|\geq\frac12\left[3-Re(z-1/z)\right]\geq\frac12(3-3/2)=\frac34.$$ The idea is from the proof of @Ryszard Szwarc.

I think that inversion does not make things easier. It is just a reformulation. Indeed assume $f$ and $g$ are polynomials and $\deg f=n.$ Then $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ for $|z|=r$ is equivalent to $|f(z^{-1})|>|g(z^{-1})|$ for $|z|=r^{-1}.$ So the same inequality has to be proved.

@Ryszard Szwarc
You are right , there is no essential difference!

Yes,  almost same difficulty. But, I didn't see the norm tricks immediately. And as a remark, I can say that low degree polynomials are easy to deal with.
